# Ventana modal problema IE

Tags: javascript

Tengo una ventana modal, y me funciona en todos los buscadores menos en internet Explorer , alguien podría decirme el porqué.

```js
function jmgModal(id, data, ok, input) {
   
    data=data || {};
    id="modal-"+id;
        var d=document.createElement("div");
        d.className="jmgmodal";
        d.id=id;
        var p=document.createElement("div");
        p.className="panel";
        var t=document.createElement("div");
        t.className="title";
        var cl=document.createElement("div");
        cl.className="close";
        cl.innerHTML='&times;';
        cl.addEventListener('click',function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var dTop=this.parentNode.parentNode;
            dTop.classList.remove("visible");
            dTop.querySelector(".panel .content").innerHTML='';
        });
        var ct=document.createElement("div");
        ct.className="content";
        var f=document.createElement("div");
        f.className="footer";
        p.appendChild(t);p.appendChild(cl);p.appendChild(ct);p.appendChild(f);
        d.appendChild(p);
        document.body.appendChild(d);
    
    var mod=document.getElementById(id),
    p=mod.querySelector(".panel"),
    t=mod.querySelector(".panel .title"),
    ct=mod.querySelector(".panel .content"),
    f=mod.querySelector(".panel .footer");

    t.innerHTML=data.title || '';
    ct.innerHTML=data.content || '';
    f.innerHTML='';
    if (!isNaN(data.width)) p.style.maxWidth=data.width+'px';
    if (!isNaN(data.height)) p.style.maxHeight=data.height+'vh';

        setTimeout(function(){
        mod.classList.add("visible");
    },50);
}
```

```html
<tr><td class="filo"><a href="javascript:parent.jmgModal('miventana',{title:'Direccion:&nbsp;<%=sDireccion%>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=sCodigo%>',width: 450,height: 50,content:'<table><tr><th>Codigo:</th><td><%=sCodigo%></td></tr><tr><th>Nombre:</th><td><%=sNombre%></td></tr><tr><th>Ciudad:</th><td><%=sCiudad%></td></tr><tr><th>Direccion:</th><td><%=sDireccion%></td></tr><tr><th>Codigo Postal:</th><td><%=sCP%></td></tr><tr><th>Telefono:</th><td><%=sTelefono%></td></tr><tr><th>Provincia:</th><td><%=sProvincia%></td></tr><tr><th>Comercial:</th><td><%=sComercial%></td></tr></table>'});">
</tr>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar tambien el HTML para poder probarlo correctamente?Echale un vistazo a [ask].

Comment: Ya esta, soy un poco novato con javascript...@GDP

Comment: No has colocado bien ese HTML, abre un td y cierra con un tr

Comment: Ya esta, al cortar se me ha pasado..

Comment: Te da algun error de consola? Esta con código servidor los parametros, y no llego a simularlo.

Comment: No me da ningun error...@GDP

Comment: ¿Has depurado el js a ver hasta donde funciona? IE es especialito...

Comment: Si... en teoria no me entra en la funcion..cl.addEventListener('click',function(ev) { @GDP

Comment: Hola ¿qué versión de IE usas para probar? Sino recuerdo mal, en las versiones antiguas (por debajo de IE9) no soportaba addEventListener, en su lugar usábamos el attachEvent

Comment: El HTML sigue estando mal no se cierra el `<a>` ni el `<td> y falta `<table>`